# Speeding up my calculation by using Vectorization

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, slice

I'm new to python, so I have some problems with the efficiency of my computation.
I'm using this code to fill my H matrix and my h vector (x_tr, x_te and c are lists):

```
for l in xrange(0, b):
    for ls in xrange(0, b):
        H[l][ls] = 1.0/n_tr * numpy.sum([numpy.exp(-((numpy.linalg.norm(x_tr[i]-c[l])**2 + numpy.linalg.norm(x_tr[i]-c[ls])**2)/(2*s**2))) for i in range(0, n_tr)])
    h[l] = 1.0/n_te * numpy.sum([numpy.exp(-((numpy.linalg.norm(x_te[j]-c[l])**2)/(2*s**2))) for j in range(0, n_te)])
```

I think it might be inefficient to use 2 loops... Is there any easy way to speed my calculation up? I've been told, that I might use Vectorization, but I somehow don't know how this works

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What is unclear to you? Have you tried a numpy tutorial?

Comment: Can I even use Vectorization to speed my calculation up?
I tried some tutorials, but I didn't really understand, how I can refer their examples to my computation

Comment: Yes, vectorization will speed up your calculation. I will try to post some help.

Comment: Vectorization is removing loops from a calculation over a matrix and a vector or a matrix and another matrix. To understand how that is done, you, might want to read up on Linear Algebra. I see that someone else has already posted a code example.

Comment: I think, you should first split up your calculation steps a bit more to make clear, what you want to do and to avoid confusion. Is it homework?

Answer (score 1):

Example of vectorization:

```
>>> x_te = np.arange(10)
>>> c = np.range(5)
>>> (x_te[:,None] - c).sum(axis=0)
array([45, 35, 25, 15,  5])
```

is equivalent to:

```
np.array([np.sum(xte[i]-c[j] for i in range(xte.size)) for j in range(c.size)])
```

That said:

as `x_te[j]` and `c[l]` are two scalars in your loops, your `np.linalg.norm(x[j]-c[i])**2` is just `(x[j]-c[i])`, right ? So your `h` could be calculated as

```
h = 1.0/n_te * numpy.sum([numpy.exp(-(x_te[: None]-c))/(2*s**2)))
```

Which should get you started for `H`...

*EDIT* You should probably check some [documentation on broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Using this code for h, I get this error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'

Comment: Which tells you that you're using lists instead of numpy arrays as I showed you in the example: `x_te` and `c` should be arrays..

Comment: ahh... yeah, you're right... I should've seen that...

x_te[i] and c[j] are no scalars, they are dependend on the input dimensionality, that's why I've used numpy.linalg.norm(...)

Comment: Ah. Then, if `x_te[i]` and `c[j]` are ndarrays, you can use the broadcasting tricks I showed you (the `x_te[:,None]-c`) with a bit of trial and error (unless yuo seriously update your question)